# Python - Print Method using variables

Tags: python, methods

I'm having trouble printing a method with a variable.

If I do  `print (pet.__str__())`, it works as expected.  However I'm trying to loop through the method using variables to replace "pet" with a variable.  I'm then assigning it to a variable and trying to print it.  When I print it, it literally prints the string `pet.__str__()` instead of calling the method.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here's a general overview of my code.  Thanks

```
pet = Pet('Taz')

my_list = ["pet", "dog", "big_dog", "small_dog"]



my_string = ["animal_variable.__str__()", "animal_variable.kind", "animal_variable.color", "animal_variable.do_tricks()"]
sentence1 = []

sentence1 = my_string[0]
print (sentence1) #DEBUGGING*****************************************
print (sentence1.replace('animal_variable', my_list[0]))
print (type(sentence1))
```

*** HERE'S THE OUTPUT I GET *******

```
animal_variable.__str__()

pet.__str__(),

class 'str'
```

*** If I do this it works as expected, however this doesn't allow me to loop through different variables in my list

```
print (pet.__str__())
```

Comment: `pet` is already variable - what other variable do you what to use ?

Comment: BTW: instead of `pet.__str__()` you should use `str(pet)` - it is prefered method.

Comment: Are you trying to `eval` a string to get your variables?

Comment: `"pet.__str__()"` is only string so don't expect that it will call a method.

Comment: "pet.__str__()" is a string... That's what I'm not getting.  If it is a string, how do I change it so that it will call the Method?

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
my_list = ["pet", "dog", "big_dog", "small_dog"]

for pet in map(Pet, my_list):
    print ("{}, Kind: {}, Color: {}\nTricks: {}".format(str(pet), pet.kind, pet.color, pet.do_tricks()))
```

If you already have a list of animals, then simply replace the for loop above with:

```
for pet in my_list:
```

Another method to use is to override `__str__` method of the class, to return the above. Something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Kind: {}, Color: {}\nTricks: {}".format(self.kind, self.color, self.do_tricks())
```

Comment: While this general idea seems to be better than the OPs, I think you misunderstood something.  It looks to me like `pet` as a string is meant to refer to the `pet` variable (maybe with eval?).  It looks, then, like all the strings in `my_list` are variable names.  Therefore, I think the loop should start with `for animal in [pet, dog, ...]`

Comment: @zondo Hmm...possibly. I will add that as another option